# Java Co-ordnates

Tags: java

I am making a 2 player java game but I need to make sure the coordinates stay on the board.

```
addPiece(1, 1, "X");
addPiece(8, 8, "O");
showBoard();
Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System. in );


System.out.println("Would you like to go first? Yes or No");
String goFirst = myScan.nextLine();

if (goFirst.equals("yes") || goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("YES")) {
    System.out.println("You are X! Please enter the coordinates of your first move");
    String coordinate = myScan.nextLine();
    String[] parts = coordinate.split(",");


    String x = parts[0];
    String y = parts[1];

    System.out.println("Moving to (" + x + "," + y + ")");

}
```

I need to make sure the piece at (1,1) doesn't leave the dimensions (past 0,0 or 8,0) how can I make it in

thinking something like

check if x is more than 8 then not a valid move
check if y is more than 8 then not a valid move
else if valid move.

thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could accept the `x` and `y` co-ordinates separately. For example:

```
int x = -1;
while (x < 0 || x > 8) {
    System.out.print("Enter a valid x-coordinate (0-8):");
    x = myScan.nextInt();
}
```

Similar for `y`

Or if you want to do it together:

```
int x = -1;
int y = -1;
while (x < 0 || x > 8 || y < 0 || y > 8) {
    System.out.print("Enter co-ordinates (x,y) between (0,0) and (8,8):");
    String[] coords = myScan.nextLine().trim().split(",");
    x = Integer.parseInt(coords[0]);
    y = Integer.parseInt(coords[1]);
}
```

This is just one of the ways. There are many other ways to achieve the same result, if you want to explore them.

Answer (score 0):

just check the bounds of the value

```
boolean invalid;
int x, y;

...

do {
  invalid = false;
  System.out.println("You are X! Please enter the coordinates of your first move");
  String coordinate = myScan.nextLine();
  String[] parts = coordinate.split(",");
  x = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
  y = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); 
  if((x < 0) || (x > 8) || (y < 0) || (y > 8)) {
    invalid = true;
    System.out.println("Invalid Coordinates");
  }
} while (invalid);
```

edit: Missed that the x,y were still strings.

Comment: You cannot compare `String`s with `<` or `>`

Comment: @kaykay missed that it's fixed.